# Crafting Polynomials with Prescribed Derivative Conditions

Tags: derivatives, polynomials

**Introductory case:** Assume that we are given an integer $k\geq 1$, a real number $a$, and a polynomial $P\in\mathbb R[X]$ which satisfies $$P(a)=a,\quad P^{(i)}(a)=0 \text{ for every } 1\leq i<k.$$ The goal is to find another polynomial $Q\in\mathbb R[X]$ which satisfies the following:

> - A stronger property than the one satisfied by $P$, namely $$Q(a)=a,\quad Q^{(i)}(a)=0 \text{ for every } 1\leq i<\ell,$$ where
>   $\ell$ is some integer greater than $k$.
> - For every $t\in\mathbb R$, the value of $Q(t)$ should be easily computable* given the value of $P(t)$.

This is for instance achievable by taking $Q:=(P-a)^2+a$ and $\ell:=2k$.

---

**Question:** Does this generalise to two values $a$ and $b$, for instance? More precisely, assume we are given an integer $k\geq 1$, two real numbers $a\neq b$, and a polynomial $P\in\mathbb R[X]$ which satisfies $$P(a)=a,\quad P(b)=b,\quad P^{(i)}(a)=0 \text{ for every } 1\leq i<k,\quad P^{(i)}(b)=0 \text{ for every } 1\leq i<k$$ The goal is to find another polynomial $Q\in\mathbb R[X]$ which satisfies the following:

> - A stronger property than the one satisfied by $P$, namely $$Q(a)=a,\quad Q(b)=b,\quad Q^{(i)}(a)=0 \text{ for every } 1\leq i<\ell,\quad Q^{(i)}(b)=0 \text{ for every } 1\leq i<\ell,$$ where
>   $\ell$ is some integer greater than $k$.
> - For every $t\in\mathbb R$, the value of $Q(t)$ should be easily computable* given the value of $P(t)$.

It would then be natural to see if this also works for three values, or more generally, for $n$ values. But I believe that if we are able to understand the case with two values, we might be able to generalise.

**Easily computable* means trying to minimise the number of required multiplications.

Comment: You'll have to specify what "easily computable" means? I believe every polynomial is always easily computable.

Comment: @Henriksupportsthecommunity It wasn't so clear to me when writing the post. But I guess what we want is to minimise the number of required multiplications. For the introductory case, we only require one multiplication to compute $Q(t)$ if we are given $P(t)$. This is a huge improvement compared to computing $Q(t)$ by simply plugging $t$ into $Q$ naively.

Comment: "minimising the number of required multiplications" still isn't precise enough that it can be used. If I can say describe a polynomial $Q$ that is computable from $P$ with 1000000 multiplications and can prove that particular polynomial can be computed using less multiplications, the number of multiplications is technically minimised, but it's probably not interesting.

Comment: @Henriksupportsthecommunity I disagree. The question just asks for ideas what to take for $Q$ and how to compute it from $P$. I'm not asking for the optimal solution.